# Taking 30 seconds longer to boot after upgrade from jessie to stretch

Tags: debian, boot-loader

On boot, I have a blank screen (blinking `_`) for over half a minute. 
I just upgraded from Debian Jessie to Stretch; I didn't have this problem before the upgrade.

I found this line in `systemd-analyze blame`:
         30.286s NetworkManager-wait-online.service

I disabled it using `systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`, but after rebooting that didn't fix the problem.

Output of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` (after disabling NetworkManager): https://pastebin.com/ws6Hqa1B

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! I googled it and found [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/64wonb/gave_up_waiting_for_suspendresume_device/) with similar problems. I [added 'noresume'](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/64wonb/gave_up_waiting_for_suspendresume_device/dgflhib/)to my kernel parameters. Specifically, I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noresume"` to `/etc/default/grub` and ran `sudo update-grub`.

It works!